# Message extensions cannot have required fields

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

My task is  to frame a Google Protocol Buffer based object that could pass a single message to the RabbitMQ with all the message/command details. I used the concept "extensions" for wrapping all the fields under a single message. But I could not declare the required data fields under extension section. My message format looks like.

```
message A 
{
    message B
    {
     extension 100 to max;

     required int32 a = 1;
     required int32 b = 2;
    }
    message C
    {
        extend B
        {
            required string name = 100;
        }
    }
    repeated A messageA = 1;
};
```

I am getting error like Message extensions cannot have required fields.

```
Commands.proto:36:34: Message extensions cannot have required fields.
```

If I have chaged the extended section as

```
message C
{
    extend B
    {
        optional string name = 100;
    }
}
```

Then it is working fine. I have also referred some links for solution http://forum.choosemuse.com/forum/developer-forum/1251-protobuf-2-6-0-required 
which showed me that have to use upgrade protoc version. Currently I am using protobuf 2.6.1. I also tried this case with protobuf 3.0.0 alpha version. But I cannot find any improvements :(. Please help me to solve this error and please correct me if I have got anything in wrong manner.

Comment: Message extensions are **not** like inheritance. Rather, they're a dual notion of that; a message with extensions is as if it contained a `map<extension_number, std::any>`. You can query the presence of an extension field in the same way you do an `any_cast`.

Comment: Hi @ Kerrek Thank you for your reply. Could you please tell me some link where I can found the complete usage if `any` in Google Protocol Buffer

Comment: Well, it's not literally true for proto2, but I used the analogy to describe the semantics. However, proto3 actually gets rid of extensions entirely and actually recommends using `any` protos for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

About that required field in extended message, I have experimented the conflict `Message extensions cannot have required fields` with protoc 3.0 as per the solution link I stated in my question http://forum.choosemuse.com/forum/developer-forum/1251-protobuf-2-6-0-required with Muse_v2.proto. But it seems we cant have the required field in extension message in proto3 too.

The error I got with "syntax="proto3";" as,

```
Commands.proto: Required fields are not allowed in proto3.
Commands.proto: Extension ranges are not allowed in proto3.
Commands.proto: The first enum value must be zero in proto3.
Commands.proto: Extensions in proto3 are only allowed for defining options.
Commands.proto:124:34: Explicit 'optional' labels are disallowed in the Proto3 syntax. To define 'optional' fields in Proto3, simply remove the 'optional' label, as fields are 'optional' by default.
```

So what I found is:

1. No need to mention explicitly the field as 'optional'. Because by
   default the fields are 'optional; in proto3.
2. Extension range is not allowed in proto3 or simply extension are
   replaced by concept called 'any' (which is under development).
3. I can't find any field prefixed with 'required' type. so the use of
   required is also not allowed in proto3
4. Also I have seen a line stating that "If you are already familiar
   with proto2 syntax, the Any type replaces extensions" but it is
   under development so we cant use it now... (ref: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#any)

It seems all these options are under development. Only proto2 is completely packed with all deliverable concepts.

It may helpful to some needs clarification as me. Please correct me If I got anything wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax here is confusing (which is my fault). Extensions do not behave like inheritance. An extension essentially adds a new field to an existing type, without having to edit the original type's definition; it does not declare any relation between the extended type and the type which lexically contains the extension.

In your example, you are declaring that the type `A.B` has an additional field called `A.C.name` which is of type `string`. Note that `name` behaves like a static constant inside `C` -- it has no effect on `C` itself. You could just as easily have defined it outside of C:

```
message A 
{
    message B
    {
     extension 100 to max;

     required int32 a = 1;
     required int32 b = 2;
    }
    extend B
    {
        required string name = 100;
    }
    message C
    {
    }
    repeated A messageA = 1;
};
```

The *only* difference between what I wrote here and what you wrote is that with what I wrote, you'd refer to the extension as `A.name`, whereas with what you wrote, it would be `A.C.name`. In both cases, the type `C` actually has no fields and no relation to `B`. The only difference is scoping of the names. Again, think of it like static constants: if you write, in C++:

```
class Foo {
  static const int I = 1;
};
```

There is no relation between `Foo` and `I` except that `I` is scoped inside of `Foo`. Extensions in Protobufs are like that.

In any case, it should be clear now why extensions cannot be required: this would mean that `name` is required *in `B`*. That is, you could not serialize an `B` without having set the extension field `name`. It would make very little sense to allow that kind of constraint: if a field is required, it should be declared directly in the message that requires it, rather than off somewhere else.

Protobuf 3 is actually removing extensions from the language, because are too confusing. So, you probably shouldn't use them in new code.

Comment: Hi @ Kenton
Thank you for reply. I also referred and found some clarification regarding this.